# as.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I am trying to compile something in g++ 4.8.1 for a class I have today.  The problem is...

> as.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>   the procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the dynamic link library
>
> `c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\as.exe.`

I have no idea what's going on here.  What did I goof up *this* time?

And yes, I am using Windows 8 and MinGW 4.8.1.

Comment: Posting some code would be nice

Comment: Can you compile nothing at all, or does this happen only with particular input?